# How to convert json array to variables in php from android post method

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, post

I have developed an android app. It sending json array of string to php. I didn't get the data in php server. And i want to insert the data into mysql. The android app using json post method. below shows the code.

MainActivity .java

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;


 import com.acs.filesharing.Person;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView tvIsConnected;
EditText etName,etCountry,etTwitter;
Button btnPost;
Person person;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
    etTwitter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTwitter);
    btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
    }

    // add click listener to Button "POST"
              btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);




}

public static String POST(String url, Person person){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
        jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;



}

private boolean isConnected() {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPost:
            if(!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread

            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.1.3/work/filesharing/1.php");
            break;
    }

}

private boolean validate() {

    if(etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(etTwitter.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String etName1= etName.getText().toString();
    String etCountry1=etCountry.getText().toString();
    String etTwitter1=etTwitter.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {



        person = new Person();
        person.setName(etName1);
        person.setCountry(etCountry1);
        person.setTwitter(etTwitter1);


        return POST(urls[0],person);

    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
 }
```

Person.java

```
 public class Person {

private String name;
private String country;
private String twitter;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getTwitter() {
    return twitter;
}

public void setTwitter(String twitter) {
    this.twitter = twitter;
}
 }
```

1.php

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","","test");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
 {
    echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
 }
  $arr = array();
  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $name = $record['name'];
  } 
  $arr = array();
  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $name = $record['name'];
  }
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user (fullname) 
      VALUES ('$name')");

 if($result == true) {
     echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
 }
 else{
     echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

I want to insert submit data into mysql. Please help me.

Comment: First you have to do this to get name from android input parameter $name=$_REQUEST['name'];                                                                              Then run the query. What you are doing in your script is trying to fetching data from Database without inserting anything which does not exist .

Comment: Insert not working? Or u want to insert multiple records

Comment: @AbuSufian I have change to $_REQUEST['name']; but it is not working.

Comment: @devpro the insert not working. The output is [{"name":"fazil","country":"ghj","twitter":"cbn"}]. I want to insert these values into mysql.

Comment: Can you do this please                                                                         $array = json_decode($result, true);
$rows = array();                                                                                             then Insert value into database

Comment: @AbuSufian  $array = json_decode($result, true); $rows = array();
  $arr = array();
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user (fullname) 
      VALUES ('$name')"); Is it correct? It is not working.

Comment: first of all HttpClient is deprecated on Android so i suggest that you move to HttpUrlConnection. Secondly i strongly suggest that you should not use mysql since its deprecated and move to mysqli or pdo